# Showing $\cos^3x-3\cos x \sin^2 x = \cos 3 x$

Tags: trigonometry

Why are these equal?
$$\cos^3x-3\cos x \sin^2 x = \cos 3 x$$
Which additional theorems apply?

Comment: @LightYagami It's an identity and he wants it proved.

Comment: I guess it's just the identity for $\cos(a+b)$ applied twice, plus perhaps some silly thing to have all the powers show that way.

Comment: It's not a homework nor a proof required. I just stumbled across it while studying continuity/differentiability  with polar coordinates. That's why I gave no approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\cos(3x)=\mathrm{Re}(e^{3ix})=\mathrm{Re}\left[(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^3\right]$$

so $$\cos(3x)=\mathrm{Re}\left[\cos^3(x)+3i\cos^2(x)\sin(x)+3i^2\cos(x)\sin^2(x) + i^3\sin^3(x)\right]$$

so

$$\cos(3x)=\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)\sin^2(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: use the compound angle formula shown below to derive the 'triple angle formula' for $\cos(3x)$:
$$
\cos(\alpha + \beta)=\cos\alpha \cos \beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta \, .
$$
Then, rewrite the RHS using the triple angle formula, and simplify your answer.